# How to simulate type conversion using PowerMock or EasyMock

Tags: mockito, powermock, easymock

```
private UserDao userDao;
public UserServiceImpl(DaoManager daoManager){

    userDao = (UserDao)daoManager.getDao(UserDao.class);
}
```

Comment: is your 'UserDao' object instanceof 'DaoManager' object?

Comment: i have solved this problem, thank you.

Comment: close this question, or answer what you did to solve, it might help others